# How to connect my central device to a peripheral running custom service?

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, packet-sniffers, nrf52

Hi i have used this tutorial : https://github.com/bjornspockeli/custom_ble_service_example to make a custom service on one of the peripheral.

I have the EVK kit NRF52832 with PCA 10040.

I'm using the standard sdk example of central/ble_app_gatts in which i am configuring the UUID to 0X1400 and type to vendor macro. And i'm enabling respective filter but i'm unable to connect my central to peripheral . Please help.

Thanks,

Dhananjay Sutariya

Comment: Are you sure that the the device running the ble_app_gatts example is advertising? You can check this by using your phone and the nRF Connect app to scan for devices. This will at least limit the problem to the central side.

Comment: Hi @YoussifSaeed - sorry for the late reply. it was actually advertising it. However i solved this by doing proper initialization of central in discovery api , cccd configure api. etc